# Random explosion of text

Tags: jquery

I am using following code to explode the value in text. I separated textbox string separate char, but while i am exploding the whole div get exploded. Help me

```
var explode=$("#text").val();
var len=explode.length;
var text="";
for(var i = 0;i < len; i++)
{
    var res=explode.charAt(i);
    $("#div").append("<span id="+i+" >"+res+"</span>");
}
for(var j=0; j < len; j++)
{
    $("#"+j).each(function(i){
        $("#"+j).css('position','relative');
        $("#"+j).animate({left:'250px',opacity:'0.5',top:'250px',bottom:'500px'});
    });
}
```

Comment: It helps if you put a demo example in jsfiddle.

Comment: And event is? keyup/keydown, or?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem causing what you say is going wrong, but ID attrs are supposed to start with A-Z. So your span IDs are invalid.

Comment: @JAAulde, no, IDs are perfectly valid...

Comment: I have to say that the title of this question is awesome

Comment: @jerome, please setup fiddle, and explain better how script should work.

Comment: @ JAAulde,No, if invalid means then how i get each char? pbm is i can not explode each char. It is jointly exploded!

Comment: @nevermind,i am new here, pls say how to fiddle it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ add html,css, js and include jquery lib, of course.. P.S. You will have to use delay, or to set interval, i have feel...

Comment: jsfiddle link   http://jsfiddle.net/87VVL/

Comment: @nevermind that depends on DOCTYPE in use and browser support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @jerome The main problem is that you're running the same animation on each char span at practically the same time. You need to randomly choose some values to animate to for each separate char span.

Comment: @jerome, do wou want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/87VVL/5/

Comment: @ nevermind,thanks. But i want each char to be exploded in different direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the term, "*explode*," you want characters to go flying in various directions. If I correctly understand your desire, then as I stated in my comment, the main problem is that you're running the same animation on each char span at practically the same time. You need to randomly choose some values to which you'll animate for each separate char span.

Here is some code which should be a little more efficient for you, and which uses random values for the animations:

```
var explode = $('#explode_text').val(),
    container = $('#explode_container'),
    getRandomInt,
    len = explode.length,
    i;

/*
 * From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    container.append(
        $('<span />').text(explode.charAt(i))
    );
}

container.children('span').each(function () {
    $(this)
        .css('position','relative')
        .animate({
            opacity: '0.5',
            left: getRandomInt(0, 250) +'px',
            top: getRandomInt(0, 250) +'px',
            bottom: getRandomInt(0, 500) +'px'
        });
});
```

**JSFiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/M8EP8/1/

Comment: ,But i can not understand abour math.floor,math.random function. Could u pls explain what happens?

Comment: JavaScript's `Math.random()` is a little odd in that it returns a decimal between 0 and 1. By manipulating that return with the min and max the way we do, and by rounding it down to a whole number, we get a workable value in the range we desired.